# super().__init__() failing with error

Tags: python-2.7

Below is my sample code on Python Inheritance.

```
class db_Conn:
    hike = 1.04

    def __init__(self,first,last,pay):
            self.first = first
            self.last = last
            self.pay = pay
            self.email = first + '.' + last + '@ibm.com'


    def full_name(self):
            return'{} {}'. format( self.first, self.last)

    def emp_raise(self):
            self.pay = int(self.pay * self.hike)


emp1 = db_Conn('amitesh','sahay',50000)
emp2 = db_Conn('amit','sharma',60000)

class Dev(db_Conn):
    def __init__(self,first,last,pay,prog): 
        super().__init__(first,last,pay)
        self.prog = prog

dev1 = Dev('amitesh','sahay',50000, 'python')
dev2 = Dev('amit','sharma',60000,'scala')

print (dev1.prog)
print(dev2.email)
```

I am getting below error::

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
dev1 = Dev('amitesh','sahay',50000, 'python')
    super().__init__(first,last,pay)
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

I am not able to figure out what mistake am I doing. Please help....!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for `super()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super) shows it needs at least one argument: the class to start searching from. This was made optional in Python 3, but as you're using 2.7, you'll need:

```
        super(Dev).__init__(first,last,pay)
```

It also says:

> **Note:** `super()` only works for [new-style class](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-new-style-class)es.

New-style classes inherit from `object`, which yours doesn't. You'll want to declare your `db_Conn` class with:

```
class db_Conn(object):
```

Answer (score 0):

For inheritance to be enabled in Python 2.7, the connection between the parent class and child class needs to be established by passing two arguments. These arguments are a reference to the child class and the self object. Thus the super function should be written as:

```
super(Dev, self).__init__(first,last,pay)
```

Also for inheritance in python 2.7, your parent class should inherit from object.